# Admob integration on intel xdk

Tags: html, github, admob, intel, intel-xdk

I made a customized 2048 game app for android using intel xdk. But i just couldn't integrate admob to my application. I dont have very much code knowledge i think that is why i cant do this. 
I am using these original codes for game
https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048?files=1 and for admob integration. And i am using this plugin for admob https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob

Where should i exactly put the codes for simple bottom banner and interstitial ads? There is a index page in 2048 files. Should put somewhere in there?

Thank you for helping it is really important for me.

Answer (score 1):

Monetization by integrating HTML5 games and AdMob plugin is a great idea.

In fact, I have done a similar thing, and the project is open source. GitHub repo: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/best2048

And, here is the APP published in AppStore:
https://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/best2048/id896349671?mt=8

Based on Gabriele's code, I added a few features:

- vivid sound effects
- i18n and translations
- admob banner

You can fork and modify for your own purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the XDK demo apps for an example of how to integrate an admob plugin. You will need to work with code, so if that is something you don't feel comfortable with you'll have to do some further investigation to learn how to work with code.